# Windows 8 Javascript set Canvas to fill screen

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm trying to create a HTML5 canvas using Windows 8 / WinJS.  Here's what I have:

```
    var body = document.getElementById("body");
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.id = "myCanvas";

    body.appendChild(canvas);

    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = document.width;
    canvas.height = document.height;

    canvasContext.fillStyle = "#f00";

    canvasContext.fillRect(canvas.width - 100, canvas.height - 50, 100, 50);
    console.log("canvas width " + canvas.width + ",  height " + canvas.height);
```

Most of this is directly from a tutorial, but for all the tutorials I've seen, the width and height are set to hard coded numbers, for example:

```
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
```

Admittedly that does work, but I want the canvas to be as big as the screen, whatever the resolution.  How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "screen", do you mean the browser window size?

If so, you can use window.outerWidth and window.outerHeight instead of document.width and document.height. Or if you use jQuery: $(window).width() and $(window).height().

Also, you want to listen to the resize event on the window so that you can reinitialize the canvas when the browser is resized.

Comment: This is a windows store app - so there is no browser.  Nevertheless - that works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the viewport with and viewport height CSS values to do this (see some information on these [here](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/))

In this specific case you could just do:

```
canvas.style.width = "100vw";
canvas.style.height = "100vh";
```

The advantage of this solution is that you don't have to load 3rd party libraries, e.g. JQuery to size to the full width / height.